# ng-include an svg for background-image

Tags: angularjs, svg, background-image

I'm trying to load an svg as background image. The svg contains angular directives, is it possible?

```
app.directive('backImg', function($timeout){ ...
```

I've made a trial http://jsfiddle.net/camaiocco/xvbuzt2o/ where the svg is loaded and applied via ng-include, but the trial to use it with the back-img directive is not working. I've tried to pass the image as a base64 of the element included, but it seems I cannot get the element.

Comment: for a background image you'll be better of doing that in your css, I see no reason to use angular to achieve that.

Comment: I need angular because I build the svg in the client